# R - dplyr. Functions with variable similar to dataframe columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this case where I am filtering on a dataframe in a function, but the dataframe has the column with a similar name as the variable I want to filter on.

example:

```
d = tibble(cond = c(1,2), b = c(1,2))

f_ = function(data, cond) {
  data = data %>% filter(b == cond)
  return(data)
}

f_(d, cond = 2)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
   cond     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2     2
```

No filtering happens (because here cond is equal to b).

this becomes an issue when I do not control the number of columns in  the data but at the minimum I know it has the b column.

Comment: Without packages: `f2 <- function(data, cond) data[data$b == cond, ]`

Answer (score 1):

We can change the function to evaluate the 'cond' not from the environment

```
f_ = function(data, cond) {
    data %>%
        filter(b == !!cond)

 }

f_(d, cond = 2)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#   cond     b
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     2     2
```